# How to make a C++ structure working fast with Boost.Sort string_sort function

Tags: c++, performance, sorting, boost

*I see the very large performance difference when sorting std::string objects compared to pairs of pointer+length and std::string works much faster*

I am doing a lot of sorting in my application and I have found that the performance bottleneck is at sorting the large arrays of strings. I know two good ways to do such sorting - use std::sort and Boost.sort functions. I am sorting the parts of large file by using pointers and string length information

I have tried to compare my performance with sorting the std::string objects and my simple pointer+length structures are much slower. *I can't imagine - why?*
The sizeof(std::string) is 32, while sizeof(my_struct) is 16 bytes. Both of them are using ::memcmp function internally to compare

To describe the problem I have made a small application that can show the performance difference between soring std::string and my structure objects:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <chrono>
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/sort/sort.hpp>

using namespace std;

#define LEN   4
#define COUNT 1000000
#define USE_BOOST_SORT

// simple structure that i think to be identical to std::string
struct test
{
    inline bool operator<(const test& a) const  noexcept
    {
        size_t minsize = len < a.len ? len : a.len;
        int res = ::memcmp(ptr, a.ptr, minsize);
        return res < 0 || (res == 0 && len < a.len);
    }
    inline size_t size() const noexcept
    {return len;}
    inline const char* data() const noexcept
    {return ptr;}
    inline const char& operator[](size_t index) const noexcept
    {return ptr[index];}

    const char* ptr = nullptr;
    size_t len = 0;
};


int main(int,char**)
{
    // stage 1.a - initialize string sorting data with randoms
    vector<string> strings;
    strings.resize(COUNT);
    int counter = 0;
    for (string& s : strings)
    {
        s.resize(LEN);
        for (char& c : s)
            c = (counter++) % 256;
    }
    // stage 1.b - make the copy of data to get deterministic results and initialize tests array
    vector<string> strings_copy = strings;
    vector<test> tests;
    tests.resize(strings_copy.size());
    for (size_t i = 0; i < tests.size(); ++i)
    {
        tests[i].ptr = strings_copy[i].data();
        tests[i].len = strings_copy[i].size();
    }

    //  stage 2. sorting
    for (size_t i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        // make the copy of data to keep order unchanged
        vector<string> to_be_sorted = strings;
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t1 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
#ifdef USE_BOOST_SORT
        boost::sort::spreadsort::string_sort(to_be_sorted.begin(), to_be_sorted.end());
#else
        sort(to_be_sorted.begin(), to_be_sorted.end());
#endif
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t2 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
        to_be_sorted.clear();
        // make the copy of tests for sorting
        vector<test> tests_for_sort = tests;
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t3 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();
#ifdef USE_BOOST_SORT
        boost::sort::spreadsort::string_sort(tests_for_sort.begin(), tests_for_sort.end());
#else
        sort(tests_for_sort.begin(), tests_for_sort.end());
#endif
        chrono::high_resolution_clock::time_point t4 = chrono::high_resolution_clock::now();

        cout << "String sort time: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t2-t1).count()
             << " msec" << endl;
        cout << "Test sort time: " << chrono::duration_cast<chrono::milliseconds>(t4-t3).count()
             << " msec" << endl;
    }
}
```

[Here is same code at IDE One](https://ideone.com/nQbRnP)

And the program output is

```
String sort time: 57 msec
Test sort time: 134 msec
String sort time: 51 msec
Test sort time: 130 msec
String sort time: 49 msec
Test sort time: 131 msec
String sort time: 51 msec
Test sort time: 130 msec
String sort time: 49 msec
Test sort time: 129 msec
String sort time: 51 msec
Test sort time: 130 msec
String sort time: 49 msec
Test sort time: 130 msec
String sort time: 51 msec
Test sort time: 132 msec
String sort time: 50 msec
Test sort time: 130 msec
String sort time: 50 msec
Test sort time: 131 msec
```

The problem remains if I will use std::sort instead of Boost.Sort.

BUT if I will try to change the **LEN** parameter to **16** and larger, my structures starts sorting with the **same speed**.

*So my question - how can I improve my code to keep it sorting as fast as std::string objects when using small strings?*

My main compiler is MSVC 2015 update 3/Win64. IDE one is using GCC internally, so this may be not a compiler problem

One more option when using Boost.Sort is to make a "Functor" objects that will wrap my structure and implement the required interface. But this way it works even slower than now

Using unsigned char datatype instead of char does not change anything

Comment: Please list the optimization settings you used to build the program in addition to the compilers used.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check whether your library is using SSO (Small String Optimization) for the string implementation.

If so,  the increased locality of reference can easily explain the difference. It also explains that the difference goes away when the strings get too large to benefit from SSO

### Proof Of Concept: `killSSO`

Runing this benchmark with the `killSSO` line commented out prints: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/13cfafce32a11c92)</kbd>**

```
String std::sort time:  193.334 msec
View std::sort time:    419.458 msec
String boost sort time: 63.2888 msec
View boost sort time:   154.191 msec
...
```

Uncommenting the line `std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), kill_SSO{});` prints: **<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c2c4e9d0320dea8b)</kbd>**

```
String std::sort time:  548.243 msec
View std::sort time:    422.26 msec
String boost sort time: 156.891 msec
View boost sort time:   154.163 msec
```

### Nonius Benchmarks

Using the [Nonius micro-benchmark framework](https://github.com/libnonius/nonius) we get:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <boost/sort/sort.hpp>
#include <boost/utility/string_view.hpp>
#include <vector>
#define NONIUS_RUNNER
#include <nonius/benchmark.h++>
#include <nonius/main.h++>

extern std::vector<std::string> const testdata;

struct kill_SSO {
    void operator()(std::string& s) const { s.reserve(20); }
    template <typename Other> void operator()(Other&&) const   {} // not needed
};

struct std_sort          { template <typename It> static void run(It b, It e) { std::sort(b,                            e); } };
struct boost_spread_sort { template <typename It> static void run(It b, It e) { boost::sort::spreadsort::string_sort(b, e); } };

template <typename C, typename Sort, bool Kill = false> void bench(nonius::chronometer& cm) {
    C c {testdata.begin(), testdata.end()};
    if (Kill) std::for_each(c.begin(), c.end(), kill_SSO{});

    cm.measure([&]{ Sort::run(c.begin(), c.end()); });
}

using view = boost::string_view; // std::string_view, boost::string_ref, gsl::span etc.
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("SSO std::sort time:  ",    [](nonius::chronometer cm) { bench<std::vector<std::string>, std_sort, false>(cm); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("SSO boost sort time: ",    [](nonius::chronometer cm) { bench<std::vector<std::string>, boost_spread_sort, false>(cm); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("String std::sort time:  ", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { bench<std::vector<std::string>, std_sort, true>(cm); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("String boost sort time: ", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { bench<std::vector<std::string>, boost_spread_sort, true>(cm); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("View std::sort time:    ", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { bench<std::vector<view>       , std_sort>(cm); })
NONIUS_BENCHMARK("View boost sort time:   ", [](nonius::chronometer cm) { bench<std::vector<view>       , boost_spread_sort>(cm); })

std::vector<std::string> const testdata = [] {
    std::vector<std::string> generated(1000000);
    auto genchar = [count=0]() mutable { return static_cast<char>(static_cast<uint8_t>(count++ % 256)); };
    std::generate(generated.begin(), generated.end(), [&] { return std::string {genchar(), genchar(), genchar(), genchar()}; });
    return generated;
}();
```

The results **<kbd>[Interactive On Plot.ly](https://plot.ly/~sehe5d88/1/)</kbd>**

[image]

Comment: Added a proof of concept benchmark that shows how to kill SO. (Also shows how to use `std::string_view`, `boost::string_view`, `boost::string_ref` or `gsl::span<>` instead of rolling your own "test" type).

Comment: [Noniused it](https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/smnJZ96VSH/), interactive benchmark plots: https://plot.ly/~sehe5d88/1/

Comment: amazing explanation for non-trivial c++ optimization feature. thank you much!